# in this case does "that" indicate "then"?

Tags: grammar

we concoct so many studies, "news" articles, and
angry screeds for perusal **that** readers can become numb.

What does **that** mean?
does it mean "then"?
or
Does **that** refer to something?

Comment: I see **so many** trees **that** I can't see the forest.

Comment: Like 'It was so cold that the water froze'. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/that): **conjunction** Example 1.2 _‘she was so tired that she couldn't think’_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, "that" here is used to indicate that readers possibly becoming numb **is caused by** concocting so many items. If you used "then" it would only mean that readers might became numb after the concocting, but not necessarily as a result. (Being an adverb, "then" would require a conjunction or something, otherwise it would be a run on sentence.)

Comment: thanks! Laurel. and Joachim, OldBrixtonian. I did not noticed "so ... that ..."